# routing to a webform using MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC 2 project runnin in .net 3.5. There are some Webforms which i have in a separate folder called "Forms". I need to routing to be implemented for this page. Like, localhost/home.aspx should be re-directed to localhost/Forms/home.aspx. When i tried using the following code,

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "home.aspx",  // URL with parameters
            @"Forms/Home.aspx"// Parameter defaults
        );
```

I get an error saying,

> The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller'

I tried this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/11/running-asp-net-webforms-and-asp-net-mvc-side-by-side.aspx), but when i try to implement

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ReportRoute",                         // Route name
 "Reports/{reportname}",                // URL
 "~/CommonReports/{reportname}.aspx"   // File
 );`
```

Iam not getting the MapPageRoute() method in my routes object. Could some one helpme how to handle this?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapPageRoute()` was only introduced in .Net 4 - which is why it is not available. There is an article about using a custom route handler that implements `IRouteHandler` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx which should do what you want.